# NReco phantomjs run script async with input and output streams

Tags: c#, phantomjs, nreco

I'm currently using the NReco phantomjs wrapper and all is well. I call an existing JavaScript file and use a stream to pass in data and an output stream to get the results which I can then turn in to a PNG and insert it into a document.

The code looks a bit like:

```
using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialisedJsonData + "\n")))
using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
       var phantomJS = new PhantomJS();
       phantomJS.Run("javascriptfile.js", null, inputStream, outputStream);

       ...
}
```

I would ideally like to call the run method async but I there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the input and output streams (only with the script filename and args).

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "RunAsync" method for this set of arguments because of `outputStream`: in this case wrapper redirects phantomjs's stdout, and output is copied to specified `Stream`. This is performed by the following code:

```
    private void ReadStdOutToStream(Process proc, Stream outputStream) {
        var buf = new byte[32 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length))>0) {
            outputStream.Write(buf, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

and this method is executed inside `Run`. It is possible to add async version of `ReadStdOutToStream` that uses `Stream.ReadAsync`, but currently wrapper has net40 target and this method is not available. Maybe its time to use net45 instead, in this case `RunAsync` for streams can be added, if it is really needed.